# Javascript active state for buttons composed of images

Tags: javascript, html, css, gsap

Javascript newb here. I am trying to make a menu that changes it's image when the button is clicked and active.

Here is the html

```
  <div id="expand_footer">                      
           <div class="footer_btn" id="ftr_btn1"> 
            <img class="shopbtns" src="outerwear_icon.png" width="66" height="87" style="padding-top:4px;" /> 
           </div>
           <div class="footer_btn" id="ftr_btn2">
            <img class="shopbtns" src="top_icon.png" width="66" height="88" style="padding-top:4px;" />
           </div>
            <div class="footer_btn" id="ftr_btn3"> 
                <img class="shopbtns" src="bottom_icon.png" width="89" height="91" style="padding-top:1px;" />
            </div>
            <div class="footer_btn" id="ftr_btn4">
                <img class="shopbtns" src="boots_icon.png" width="66" height="80" style="padding-top:10px;" /> 
           </div>
 </div>
```

and the css

```
.footer_btn {
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    width:25%; /* percentage of stage to occupy */
    margin-top:0px; /*adjust spacing between text and image */
    padding:0!important;
    cursor:pointer;
    z-index: 405!important;
}
```

I'm switching from AS3 to JS so apologize if the question seems silly. Would the best way to accomplish this just be in CSS or can Javascript handle this. I'm not using Jquery. (avoiding the library load) I am using GSAP so perhaps there is a way with that or? Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: can you prepare a quick jsFiddle please with your image assets with absolute URLs (so they can load properly)? Also, can you edit your question to include the details you put as a comment in @DPac's answer?

Comment: I've solved it by layering an active state of the button under the clickable button using divs and z index - then using the visibility setting to control the appearance of the button when it's been clicked/active. Sorry I literally did not have time to build a JsFiddle!

Comment: I see. Glad you were able to resolve it on your own. This solution you applied was one of the ideas I had in my mind I.e. playing with visibility. Still, would have liked to be able to actually change background image on the fly ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you possibly use [background-image](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp) and [selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp)?

```css
.footer_btn {
//Your css
}

.footer_btn:hover {
  background-image: url('image.jpg');
}
```

Comment: The problem is there are 4 footer buttons, each one controls the scroll of a carousel - there are 8 products in the carousel and 4 categories, so each category button also needs to link to the location of the carousel  or be active and become inactive after each button is clicked. I tried using the style.display none and block but it's not giving me quite what I need.